# How to install uncompressed version of Angular2 using NPM?

Tags: angular, npm

How to install uncompressed version of Angular2 using NPM ?

i use : npm install angular2

Answer (score 0):

Actualy it contains the uncompressed file with the extension `.dev.js`

Answer (score 0):

For windows use

1. npm install -g angular-cli
2. ng new PROJECT_NAME
3. cd PROJECT_NAME
4. ng serve